# Communication Android to PC using bluetooth to send a text file

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Hello I am new to Android. I want to communicate android with pc to send a text file. 
I am trying to communicate using following code.
I am using bluetooth dongle to pc. 
When i run application it get crashed without any error. Please help me in communication.

```
    enter code here

         package com.exam.bluetooth2;

         import java.io.IOException;
         import java.io.OutputStream;
         import java.util.Set;
         import java.util.UUID;


         import android.R;
         import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
         import android.app.Activity;
         import android.app.ProgressDialog;
         import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
         import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
         import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
         import android.content.Intent;
         import android.os.Bundle;
         import android.os.Handler;

         import android.os.Message;
         import android.util.Log;
         import android.view.View;
         import android.view.Window;
         import android.view.WindowManager;
         import android.widget.Button;
         import android.widget.EditText;
         import android.widget.Toast;


      public class Main extends Activity implements Runnable 
      {
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    Button mScan;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private ProgressDialog mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog;
    private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
        mScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View mView) 
            {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message1", 2000).show();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
                    {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new                                     Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this,        DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode, Intent mDataIntent) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

        switch (mRequestCode) 
        {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
                    String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
                    Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
                    mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
                    mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,  "Connecting...", mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : " + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(), true,   false);
                    Thread mBlutoothConnectThread = new Thread(this);
                    mBlutoothConnectThread.start();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(),  10000).show();
                    //pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice); This method is replaced by progress       dialog with thread
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    ListPairedDevices();
                    Intent connectIntent = new Intent(Main.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Message", 2000).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    private void ListPairedDevices() 
    {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + " " +      mDevice.getAddress());
            }
        }

    //  Object device = null;
    //  String dv = device.toString();
    //    if(dv.contains("00:1B:EE:82:31:1E"))
     //   {
     //   mBluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice) device;
     //   }
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            mBluetoothSocket =        mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            String messsage = "Welcome to SmarTec";
            byte[] tosend=messsage.getBytes();
            OutputStream out=mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            out.write(tosend);
        }
        catch (IOException eConnectException) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
             closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
             return;
        }
    }

    private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) 
    {
        try 
        {
            nOpenSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "SocketClosed");
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotCloseSocket");
        }
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() 
    {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Device Connected", 5000).show();

        //    Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Option.class);
        //    startActivity(in);

        }
    };


      /*    public void sendtext(View v) {//button click

        Set<BluetoothDevice> bd = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        sendDataToPairedDevice("message1");
        }

        private void sendDataToPairedDevice(String message ){       
            byte[] toSend = message.getBytes();
            try {
             UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64- 0800200c9a66");
             BluetoothSocket socket =       mBluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
             OutputStream mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();
             mmOutStream.write(toSend);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e( "Exception during write", e.toString());
         }
        }
        */
}

    enter code here

      package com.exam.bluetooth2;

      import java.util.Set;

        import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

        ListView mPairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        mPairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) 
        {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) 
            {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName() + "\n" + mDevice.getAddress());
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            String mNoDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mNoDevices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) 
        {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
    }

    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> mAdapterView, View mView, int mPosition, long mLong) 
        {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String mDeviceInfo = ((TextView) mView).getText().toString();
            String mDeviceAddress = mDeviceInfo.substring(mDeviceInfo.length() - 17);
            Log.v(TAG, "Device_Address " + mDeviceAddress);

            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("DeviceAddress", mDeviceAddress);
            Intent mBackIntent = new Intent();
            mBackIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mBackIntent);
            finish();
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vijay,

You need to check few thinks below:

1. Add bluetooth permission in manifest file.
2. If device is not supporting bluetooth, then you get bluetooth adapter value null. So need to check that also.
3. Also its better to create broadcast receiver with bluetooth actions.